# Find file and cd into it

Tags: bash

I am attempting to find multiple files, then quit after the first match and then cd into this match, I have attempted:

```
find `pwd` -iname 'tensorflow' -type d -exec echo {} \; -quit | xargs -I{} cd {}
```

However, this does nothing and it won't enter into that directory.

Comment: No error message printed? How can you be sure if the chdir did not happen?

Comment: @Jetchisel Nothing printed, I checked with `pwd` and I'm still in the same directory

Comment: So the expectation is to land you in different directories after the script is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `/usr/bin/cd`, it's not an executable. You have to run it in current shell, not in subshell as part of pipeline.

Do not use backticks. Prefer `$(...)`.

`find pwd`? Just `find .`, you *are* already in pwd.

`-exec echo {} \;`? Just `-print` it.

```
dir=$(find . -iname 'tensorflow' -type d -print -quit)
cd "$dir"
```

Comment: I have not used variables before, the `find pwd` was so that I get the full path. Are you suggesting this cannot be done in one line?

Comment: You can do anything in one line. `dir=$(...); cd "$dir"`. `cd "$(...)"`

Comment: That is a neat hack! I was not aware of this, thank you

Comment: This worked brilliantly! I have attempted it with my code, just because I had other things in mind.